# How to replace a bunch of URLs with the first URL of that list

Tags: javascript

first of all I'm sorry if my question is a bit confusing, English isn't my native language, so I need to replace a bunch of URLs with the first URL of that list, the URLs keep changing, here's the text I wanna replace:

```
[rotate=url1.usa.gov;url2.facebook.com/;http://9gag.com]
```

The only thing that doesn't change is `[rotate=....]` and the URLs are divided by a `;` I want the result to be:

```
url1.usa.gov
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
var str = str.replace(/\[rotate=.*;.*\]/g, '$0');
```

But when I do that, the result is: `$0`
How can I do this?

Comment: Use captured group `.replace(/\[rotate=(.*?);.*\]/, '$1')`

Comment: If you don't like regex, then first `split(';')` and then on the first item in splitted array again `split('=')` and get first element from it.

Comment: @Tushar thank you very much, you solved my problem.

Comment: @Tushar fails on `[rotate=A]` and `[rotate=A;B] and a random ] here`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace` interprets a number of special sequences starting with `$` in the replacement string, but `$0` is not one of them.

If you want to extract substrings from a match, you need capturing groups (`(` ... `)`). Anything matched by them is available as properties on the match object as well as `$1`, `$2`, ... in a replacement string.

In your case I'd go with

```
str.replace(/\[rotate=([^;\]]*)(?:;[^\]]*)?\]/g, '$1')
```

That is:

```
\[rotate=      // find '[rotate=', followed by
(  [^;\]] *  ) // 0 or more characters that are not ';' or ']'
               // (and remember this part as $1),

(?:            // group, but don't capture
   ;           //   a literal ';'
   [^\]] *     //   0 or more characters that are not ']'
)?             // this group is optional
\]             // a literal ']'
```

This is robust even if there is only one URL in the list: `[rotate=example.com]` will turn into `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use regular expression, you could try:

```
str.replace(/\[rotate=([^;\[\]]*)(;[^\[\];]*)*\].*/g, '$1')
```

which returns

```
"url1.usa.gov"
```

see [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/lpAwWY/4).

Comment: Fails on `[rotate=A] and a random ] here` and `[rotate=A;B] and a random ] here`.

Comment: @melpomene I'm not sure what you mean by fail here. You can see https://regex101.com/r/lpAwWY/1 for the result? If I'm understanding correctly, `[rotate=A;B]` and `[rotate=A]` should both get you `A`?

Comment: @melpomene updated https://regex101.com/r/lpAwWY/4 , but actually I do not prefer regex here, you should separate this to several steps.